# uploaded image display as rotated in yii

Tags: php, html, css, image, yii

After uploading image when i view on the web page it display as rotated. This happen only for few images not for all.
Here is html code of displaying an image.

```
<td width="29%" height="152" valign="top">
    <div>
        <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . Yii::app()->params->path . $model->image_path; ?>"/>
    </div>
</td>
```

File upload code in Controller

```
$image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, "image_path");
if (isset($image->name)) {
    $image_path_name = uniqid("children_photo_") . '.' . $image->getExtensionName();
    $modelChildren->image_path = $image_path_name;
    $path = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') . Yii::app()->params->children_logo_path . $image_path_name;
    $image->saveAs($path);
}
```

Comment: There is no relation between your question and your code.! so the problem might be in your image.

Comment: Are you capturing/uploading the image from a mobile device?

Comment: Yes. I have tried exif_read_data() function of php but it gives Fatal error: Call to undefined function exif_read_data().